# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS freezes after login screen

Tags: 18.04, login, gui

I'm new to using Ubuntu [dual boot with windows 7] and after login my Ubuntu keeps freezing at the purple screen. It does not happen every single login and sometimes it works fine just after a full shutdown. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> works and enables me to get into the terminal, so I assume it is the graphical interface.

I've been struggling with the following issue for two weeks and tried to fix it using various solution already suggested in comparable posts. First I thought it was due to automatic updates by Ubuntu so I turned this feature off, but now the problems have returned. Currently I'm at a loss and I do not know what else to try to fix it. The only option that works is to every time re-install Ubuntu from a bootable USB, but this is not a sustainable solution.

Any help would be much appreciated and I'm happy to provide all the required details if you can inform me how to get them.

Thank!

Rob

**Update 1**

I tried the following code in the root menu via the advanced options for Ubuntu:

```
sudo fsck -f /
```

Output:

fsck from util-linu 2.31.1

e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)

Pass 1: Checking inodes blocks and sizes

Pass 2: Checking directory structure

Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity

Pass 4: Checking reference counts

Pass 5: Checking group summary information

/dev/sda3: 275417/1222992 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 2116101/4882432 blocks

It did not come back with any (for me) obvious error messages.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that because you mention Windows 7, that you've got an older computer.

You may have a problem with an older computer, with an older GPU. Try this...

- boot to recovery mode
- choose root access

type:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /      # to remount the disk r/w

sudo pico /etc/gdm3/custom.conf # edit this file
```

change:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Then reboot.

**Update #1:**

If this is a **work** computer, your IT folks would probably have a problem with you tinkering on "their" system. Contact them. If however, this is **your work** computer, let try some simple things...

Lets first check your file system for errors.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried the suggestion but it did not make a difference.

As for the computer. The laptop is only 2 months old, but it is a work laptop. The company still uses windows 7 as default, not sure why. Would this change your view on the issue?

Comment: @Rob_B please see the update to my answer. Report back.

Comment: I need linux to function for work. So the IT department is in agreement, yet they do not offer their support. I added the output of the code you suggested to the original post, no weird error messages to my knowledge.

Comment: Fair enough. Do you have any GNOME extensions installed? Go [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/local/) to check, and temporarily turn them ALL off, log out, log in, and retest. Show me `ls -al .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Report back.